# Check for ImageMagick current version based on that uninstall or Install

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

We are going for penetration testing and for that reason I need to upgrade ImageMagick on our server to 7.0.2-2 because previous version 6.7.x.x (which we currently run) has some high vulnerabilities and to get rid of them we plan to update this.
I want to mange it through ansible and to do a separate installation I have a script but this script doesn't check if there is any previously installed version. It would be great if some can help me in writing a script which first checks for any previous version if there is one uninstalls it and then do new installation of upgraded version.
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain the version by parsing it out of the first line of output from

```
identify --version
```

e.g., on a nearly up-to-date host:

> $ identify --version
>
> Version: ImageMagick 7.0.1-1 Q16 x86_64 2016-06-24
>   http://www.imagemagick.org Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2016
>   ImageMagick Studio LLC License:
>   http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php Features: Cipher DPC
>   HDRI  Delegates (built-in): bzlib djvu fftw fontconfig freetype jbig
>   jng jpeg lcms lqr lzma openexr png tiff wmf x xml zlib

or on a not-so-up-to-date host:

> $ identify --version
>
> Version: ImageMagick 6.6.9-6 2011-04-28 Q16
>   http://www.imagemagick.org Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2011
>   ImageMagick Studio LLC Features:

Use "sed" or your favorite editor to extract the version string:

```
identify --version|sed "-e s/Version: ImageMagick //" -e "s/ .*//"|head -1
```

Comment: many thanks. One more quick question about ImageMagick. When I do convert -version, its output is Version: ImageMagick 7.0.1-1. While when I do sudo convert -version then output changes to  Version: ImageMagick 6.7.x.x. I believe to have two different version installed but what differenc sudo makes to shell out different output. Also how to completely remove older IMage Magick completely from machine. Many thanks in advance and for previous answer as well :)

Comment: @MadhrendraLathar that's not really a question about ImageMagick but about "sudo" and your shell.  Apparently you're set up to use a different code path under sudo, maybe via some directory that you as a regular user can't access.